# how have the done this?

Tags: jquery

http://www.jwt.com/

i've used a website scraper tool so i could work out how they have done the grid on the home page with the filters.

when i run it displays an error generated from this code

```
errors: {
        parsererror: {
            title: 'Unable to parse server response',
            subtitle: 'Please try again later.',
            image: {
                file: '/images/content/errors/error04.jpg',
                width: 390,
                height: 294
            }
        },
```

anyone know why i can't get this to work locally?

Comment: You should have a more descriptive title.

Comment: Because the server doesn't like people scraping it.

Comment: So you stole some code from a website that you want to use, and want to know why it doesn't work when you paste it in to your own stuff?

Answer (score 2):

"server response" seems to indicate that the site is talking to the web server to get dynamic content, which seems necessary considering how the original site updates dynamically.  If you copy all the code locally, it is likely trying to talk to your local machine as if it were the server, but your local machine doesn't have the server code.

You can't  simply copy the HTML of a dynamic site and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with view>page source to work out how they have achieved an effect?